# Jade -- nested html tag in one line

Tags: pug

According to Jade documentation, I can write:

```
div
    ul
         li.active one
         li two
         li three
```

I am considering something like this:

```
div - ul
    li.active one
    li two
    li three
```

How can I put multiple html tags in one line? I did not find a way in the documentation.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Thank you for asking @shrekuu it helped me a lot

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
div: ul
    li.active one
    li two
    li three
```

https://pugjs.org/language/tags.html

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it is better to use Tag Interpolation: #[a(href="#") foo]

Comment: How to write something like <div>New app version number<span>:</span></div> to render in one line, where the parent contains text + element.

Comment: @sajith I think you can do it like: https://codepen.io/shrekuu/pen/WOGrQE .    In this example, you have to use the chrome developer tool to examine the output.
You can checkout more from the doc: https://pugjs.org/language/tags.html

Comment: Thank you @Shrek. The example is working fine. But in my project, I tried the example and it still generates div and span in two lines. I'm using jade-gulp 0.8.0 in my project. That could be the reason. Thanks anyway.