# write inline tags jade

Tags: html, pug

I want to write:

```
<ul><li><a href="#">one</</a></li></ul><ul><li><a href="#">two</</a></li></ul><ul><li><a href="#">three</</a></li></ul>
```

I have tried this from this question but it only inlines the `<ul>` how can I inline all `<li>`s

[Jade -- nested html tag in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232733/jade-nested-html-tag-in-one-line)

Thanks!

Comment: Your 'a' tags are not properly closed

Answer (score 0):

The following jade:

```
ul: li: a(href='#') one
ul: li: a(href='#') two
ul: li: a(href='#') three
```

Should render into the following html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want all the `<li>` tags under one `<ul>` use the following jade:

```
ul
  li: a(href='#') one
  li: a(href='#') two
  li: a(href='#') three
```

This will then render into the following html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But I want the <li> tags to be inline too @adam-morgan

Comment: Why? It shouldn't affect what's rendered on the front end.